# Backwards Length Extension Attack

Tags: hash, length-extension

Can SHA 256 be modified to make it vulnerable to length extension attack both by appending text to the front and adding text to the end?

Comment: Without restriction on "modified", the answer is obviously yes. Hint for a surreptitious modification: that's possible with only a change in the 256-bit IV constant, and one of the reason to use a [nothing up my sleeves number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number) there.

Comment: That last part of your question is unclear. Do you need to be able to add "text" to the front *in addition* to the normal length extension attack that adds text to the end? Or do you need to be able to prepend and append *at the same time*?